# Output file empty when running scripts

Tags: python, stdout

Is it always the case that the output file of STDOUT/ print on a python script or any other script will appear empty when opened until the scripts completed execution?

If for instance, I am running a program, that keeps printing a value at every iteration and writes it to an output file. Now, this program runs for a long time and I want to check the progress by looking into the output file. But on opening, it appears empty.

So will I be able to look at the output in the file only on completion of execution? If so why is that?

Comment: Is this what you are looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/107705/disable-output-buffering ?

Comment: @fredtantini yes, thank you! Output buffering, that's the term I was looking for.